# redirecting browser to a new image, with content type image/png in PHP

Tags: php, http, header

I have a php script which generates an image, and is used (mainly) like this:

```
<img src="user_image.php?id=[some_guid]" />
```

The script uses a class I wrote to display an image matching that ID. There are a number of things that could go wrong though, and each of them throws an exception. So I have something like this:

```
<?php

try {

    if( ! isset($_GET['id']) ) throw new Exception;

    $images = new User_Images;
    $images->display($_GET['id']);

} catch( Exception $e ) {

    header('location: images/link_error.png');

}
```

If I view this from the browser, everything is fine -- if there was an error the address in the address bar changes to `images/link_error.png` and displays that instead.

But when this script is used in an `<img>` tag, and there is an error grabbing the image, it doesn't show up at all.

Do header redirects not work this way? What is another way that I can do this?

### update

There is no problem, browser redirects work perfectly this way, the issue was that my browser was caching the empty image that was returned before the redirect was put in. A hard refresh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> for Firefox) fixed it and it started working like normal.

Comment: "there is an error grabbing the image" - what kind of error? Slow connection?

Comment: no, just processing errors -- if the image with the spec. ID doesn't exist, or the user doesn't have permission to view it, or if there's some server error preventing it from loading (watermark fails for some reason, etc), or anything else that could throw an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hummm... My guess is that the

```
header('Location: images/link_error.png');
```

Because **headers were previously sent**?

Try placing an `ob_start()` on the top of your file and see if it solves your problem.

---

Here is a simple way to debug this:

```
try {
    if (!isset($_GET['id'])) throw new Exception;

    $images = new User_Images;
    $images->display($_GET['id']);
} catch (Exception $e) {

    if (headers_sent() === false)
    {
        header('Location: images/link_error.png'); // also try using the absolute URL here
    }

    else
    {
        echo file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif');
    }
}
```

If the Google logo shows up, you need to trace where you're outputting data or use `ob_start()` + `ob_end_clean()`.

---

<kbd>this tag is really nice</kbd>!

Comment: Mmmm, good point! But according to his source code, no output takes place. (If it's the full code.)

Comment: it isn't that, because visiting the page gives the correct result, and when the browser goes to fetch an image it does it in a separate request so the headers from the page including the image tag have nothing to do with it.

Comment: good idea, I tried it but unfortunately the image still simply doesn't show.

Comment: @Carson: Have you tried it using the `images/link_error.png` absolute URL?

Comment: Try dropping the whole code and just do the header redirect, does that work?

Comment: okay, I put `header('....etc` at the top of the source file, and it works fine -- what's interesting is that the existing images _still show up_ even though the redirect is at the top of the source file... maybe caching has been making this more elusive than necessary?

Comment: ah yes, I put the `header()` call back where it belonged and did a hard refresh and it worked -- I didn't think browsers would cache _nothing_ for image files...

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the help! And uh... Sorry for not trying `ctrl+F5` a little earlier :)

Comment: Browsers have a funny way of caching php pages/images despite http headers specifying otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting - I would expect a call to a `<img>` tag to work with a redirect. Anyway, it might not. I'd be interested to hear why not. Anyone?

The easiest workaround that comes to mind is passing through the error image using `fopen()` and `fpasshtru()`.

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't work / redirect. I've done stuff like this before and it always worked.

Comment: Odd, am I doing the redirect right? Do I have to do something else with the headers?

Comment: The header looks fine, but maybe you should analyze the script's response on a deeper level. I don't know whether Firebug can help - a text-level fetcher/browser like wget or lynx might.

Comment: It doesn't work because by the time the header gets sent to the browser, output has already been sent - all of the HTML up to the <img> tag.

Comment: Huh? The HTML containing the img tag, and the image are two different resources, are they not? `user_image.php` is rendered independently from the HTML.

Comment: You're right Pekka, I confused the "output already sent" issue, it doesn't apply here. Seems you just can't send a 301 as the source of an img tag. Not sure if that's defined in the HTML spec somewhere or just a browser implementation issue?

Comment: It seems like the issue is solved and it worked with a redirect. Check out the discussion in Alix Axel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just give the error image a default ID (i.e. zero) and use $images->display(0)? Then the error image is handled exactly like the successful case.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to avoid adding special cases to the class functions though, so far everything just throws an exception and they are handled at the level that they need to be

Comment: Well, the problem is that you're doing a redirect (header: Location...) inside an <img> tag... that doesn't work. It does work calling the script in the browser since you're redirecting the whole page there. You need to return an image from this script even in the error case. If you don't want it to be part of the function, fopen it in the exception and send the file contents after the header "content-type: image/png".

Comment: I suppose I will have to, although I am extra curious about this now since Alix Axel said he has done this before and it worked

Comment: @Carson: Actually I think Thilo may be right, I haven't done it *exactly* the same way you are. Still if Thilo is indeed right the `headers_sent()` function in my answer should catch that scenario.

Comment: See my comment below. You can't send a 301 redirect after you've already sent HTML. That's why it works calling this directly in the browser, but not from inside an <img> tag.

Comment: There wasn't any HTML sent before the redirect -- fetching the images on the page is done in separate requests. Also it turns out that my browser cached _nothing_ as the image that wasn't showing up, so it wasn't even trying to get the broken link picture.

Comment: Thilo, I think you're wrong. A call to an image resource is essentially identical with a call to any other resource. All resources should be able to return a 301 header, and cause the browser to look at the new address. I need to see it black and white that it won't work for images before I believe this. Also, the rendering of the HTML and the rendering of the image are two entirely separate processes, and the fact that HTML has been output in one process, does not affect the image file and its ability to emit `header()`s in the slightest. Unless I am totally overlooking something.

Comment: Hmm... I remember having this same problem and that was my solution, but I'm open to corrections :) In any case, sending the error image as image/png directly should do the trick, no?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of places like PhotoBucket just display an error image when there are problems loading the requested one. This is usually a pre-constructed image that just says "Image Error" or whatever. When images are being put together dynamically, there aren't many other options than this other than returning a 404.